# OpenVpn Client credentials security, key crt generation

Tags: security, openvpn, private-key

I'm curious what is Your opinion on openvpn **client** crt/key security

In most cases (tutorials), the clients key/crt are generated on the same openvpn server, and no one cares about the future. This is secure, as long as someone gets into the server :)

There are many scenarios of how this can be a thread. 
I'd like to prevent '**client spoofing'** - where privilege person/admin (inside attack) steel user credentials (key/crt) directly from the server, and use them connect as someone else.

I guess, the only way to prevent this:

1. Generate key/crt on the server
2. Deliver them to client
3. Remove **key** from server (keep crt do You can revoke it)

Drawback: if user ask for key again - Sorry - You don't have it, You need to generate new key/crt pair (and revoke the old one!)

What would You think about that?

Some topic:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66948/openvpn-storage-location-and-creation-of-keys-certificates

Comment: This is one reason why multi-factor authentication is a thing. Cert+user/pass or cert+user/pass+TOTP.

Comment: Sure
I'm using: https://github.com/evgeny-gridasov/openvpn-otp
But still - if You break in to Server, You can get the 'OTP base key' :/